# Efficient algorithm to get the combinations of all items in object

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization, binomial-coefficients

Given an array or object with n keys, I need to find all combinations with length `x`. 

Given `X` is variable. `binomial_coefficient(n,x)`.

Currently I'm using this:

```
function combine(items) {
    var result = [];
    var f = function(prefix, items) {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            result.push(prefix + items[i]);
            f(prefix + items[i], items.slice(i + 1));
        }
    }
    f('', items);
    return result;
}

var combinations = combine(["a", "b", "c", "d"]);
```

The output is:

```
["a", "ab", "abc", "abcd", "abd", "ac", "acd", "ad", "b", "bc", "bcd", "bd", "c", "cd", "d"]
```

So if I want the binomial coefficient `x=3` from `n=4` I select all the strings with length equal to three. {abc, abd, acd, bcd}.

So I do this in two steps.

Is there a more efficient algorithm with smaller complexity?

***Link:*** [*Solution performance (JSPerf)*](https://jsperf.com/binomial-combinations-from-array)

Comment: Thank you all. I've created a jsperf test with all the answers [here](https://jsperf.com/binomial-selection), after testing several values in different browsers and PCs I think David has the fastest solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm is almost `O(2^n)`, you can discard a lot of combinations, but the num of elements will be `(n! * (n-x)!) / x!`.

To discard the useless combinations you can use an indexed array.

```js
 function combine(items, numSubItems) {
        var result = [];
        var indexes = new Array(numSubItems);
        for (var i = 0 ; i < numSubItems; i++) {
            indexes[i] = i;
        }
        while (indexes[0] < (items.length - numSubItems + 1)) {
            var v = [];
            for (var i = 0 ; i < numSubItems; i++) {
                v.push(items[indexes[i]]);
            }
            result.push(v);
            indexes[numSubItems - 1]++;
            var l = numSubItems - 1; // reference always is the last position at beginning
            while ( (indexes[numSubItems - 1] >= items.length) && (indexes[0] < items.length - numSubItems + 1)) {
                l--; // the last position is reached
                indexes[l]++;
                for (var i = l +1 ; i < numSubItems; i++) {
                    indexes[i] = indexes[l] + (i - l);
                }
            }        
        }
        return result;
    }

    var combinations = combine(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 3);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(combinations));
```

For example, the first combination have the indexes: `[0, 1, 2]` and the elements `["a", "b", "c"]`. To compute the next combination, It get the last index `2` and try to increment, if the increment is lower than the max position (in this case `4`), the next combination is reached, but if It is not, It must increment to a previous index.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach with stress on the length of the array and the still needed items.

Basically `combine()` takes an array with the values to combine and a size of the wanted combination results sets.

The inner function `c()` takes an array of previously made combinations and a start value as index of the original array for combination. The return is an array with all made combinations.

The first call is allways `c([], 0)`, because of an empty result array and a start index of 0.

```js
function combine(array, size) {

    function c(part, start) {
        var result = [], i, l, p;
        for (i = start, l = array.length; i < l; i++) {
            p = part.slice(0);                       // get a copy of part
            p.push(array[i]);                        // add the iterated element to p
            if (p.length < size) {                   // test if recursion can go on
                result = result.concat(c(p, i + 1)); // call c again & concat rresult
            } else {
                result.push(p);                      // push p to result, stop recursion
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    return c([], 0);
}

console.log(combine(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

We could create just those combinations we are interested in. Also, rather than cloning arrays by using slice in each call, we can use a pointer to the original array. Here's one version. Converting it to recursion without an external global variable is left as an exercise.

```js
function choose(ns,r){
  var res = [];

  function _choose(i,_res){
    if (_res.length == r){
      res.push(_res);
      return;

    } else if (_res.length + ns.length - i == r){
      _res = _res.concat(ns.slice(i));
      res.push(_res);
      return
    }

    var temp = _res.slice();
    temp.push(ns[i]);

    _choose(i + 1,temp);
    _choose(i + 1,_res);
  }

  _choose(0,[]);
  return res;
}

var combinations = choose(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 3);
console.log(JSON.stringify(combinations));
```

Answer (score 2):

And here's the true recursion.

```js
function seq(a,b){
  var res = [];
  for (var i=a; i<=b; i++)
    res.push(i);
  return res;
}

function f(n,k){
  if (k === 0)
    return [[]];
    
  if (n === k)
    return [seq(1,n)];
    
  let left = f(n - 1, k - 1),
      right = f(n - 1, k);
    
  for (let i=0; i<left.length; i++)
    left[i].push(n);
  
  return left.concat(right);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(4,3)))
```